# Click a link to load mobile site, but also preserve url path to load exact parallel page

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried finding a similar inquiry but found nothing. I recently created the mobile version of my site at m. and added a snippet I found that will display a link to navigate to the mobile site from the regular, or regular from the mobile, by looking at the device being used. That works fine. But what I'd like to add to it is that, when you click on the link, it preserves the page you are currently on, but just loads the alternate device version for you, so you don't need to research what you were looking for when you get sent to the other site version.

So if you are on https://m.retroreprints.com/production?show_id=1, and click the link, it will load https://archive.retroreprints.com/production?show_id=1. Basically just swapping the m. with the archive. I currently have the exact URL in the href to go to the root, but I want it to look at where you are, and use that URL in the link. Below is the code I currently have at the top of the page of the mobile site. The main site is similar but tweaked in the If Else

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var element = document.getElementById('mobile');
    if (isMobile) {
        element.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "<center>You are using a Desktop computer. Go <a href='https://archive.retroreprints.com'>HERE</a> to view the site optimized for your device.</center>";
    }
</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: use `<iframe>` tag, `<iframe src="https://archive.retroreprints.com/production?show_id=1" title="description">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirects like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isMobile) {
        window.location.href = "https://mobile.mysite.com";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "https://desktop.mysite.com";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I already have this part. I want to have it look at the current page, and load the parallel page. I dont want it to be a static url in the redirect.

Comment: Then you might switch to using responsive design. Having separate mobile/desktop sites is not a good thing today, and separate URLs is one such problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for

Can we just fetch the URL and replace the host name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  var element = document.getElementById('mobile');
  var loc = window.location.href
  if (isMobile && loc.contains('archive.retroreprints')) {
    let redirectURL = loc.replace('archive.retroreprints', 'm.retroreprints');
    element.innerHTML ='<center>You are using a Desktop computer. Go <a href='+redirectURL+'>HERE</a> to view the site optimized for your device.</center>';
  } else if(loc.contains('m.retroreprints')) {
    let redirectURL = loc.replace('m.retroreprints', 'archive.retroreprints');
    element.innerHTML ='<center>You are using a Desktop computer. Go <a href='+redirectURL+'>HERE</a> to view the site optimized for your device.</center>';
  }
<script>
```

And finally, append the string loc in the message u need to show?

Comment: @Aaron Apologies if the answer didn't make sense, I thought the requirement is just to update the link in the message with the proper hostname and path to route the user back to either desktop/mobile on link click.

Comment: Your script would be close, as the .replace function would change the string of the url and could be used to alter the destination url when clicked. The issue Ive been facing for hours this morning is that when I use a variable to try and pull in current loaded url, .replace doesnt seem to be doing anything. When I put the end product variable in to the href line in the IF ELSE statement, it just keeps reloading the current page.